Is there any way to download files from TG-channel with using telebot python module?
I tried to make a bot that downloads files from Telegram channel, but except of good code I don't get files that may be downloaded in my directory. I tried this code:
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['document'])
def main(message):
    if message.document.file_name.startswith("schedule"):
        print(f"{Fore.GREEN}got this file: {message.document.file_name}")

        id = message.document.file_id
        info = bot.get_file(id)

        downloaded_file = bot.download_file(file_info.file_path)
        path = os.path.join(directory, message.document.file_name)

        with open(path, 'wb') as channel_file:
            channel_file.write(downloaded_file.content)


Is there any mistake that I've made?

Code looks fine at first glance except for the fact that you have not included portion where the variable directory is defined. You might have to look into output for potential errors.

Also you are defining info but using file_info.file_path. Python Inbuilt id is being overwritten by your reassigniation to id = message.document.file_id which is not recommended but should not have effect on the outcome.
